# how to count same elements in different arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I've a list that contains 4 sized arrays:

[image]

These arrays have 4 elements. I want to use another list that contains these arrays' first element's count. In addition, if their first elements are same, they should be summation. For example:

```
list[0] = {1,2,3,4}
list[1] = {1,1,5,3}
list[2] = {1,2,5,8}
list[3] = {2,2,3,3}
list[4] = {3,5,5,6}
list[5] = {4,4,4,4}
list[6] = {4,5,5,6}
```

So, anotherList should be:

```
anotherList = {3, 1, 1, 2}
```

How can I do this?

EDIT: Expected result is:

[image]

Comment: I don't follow your example at all. Why 3, 1, 1, 2? What does that have to do with summation? What do you mean by "first elements count"? I'm entirely confused.

Comment: What stoped you from doing this? (What have you tried so far)

Comment: @JonSkeet if this was sql it would be equivalent to the sql `select count(column_1) from list group by column_1`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: And for some reason it's 1-based rather than 0-based? Okay. Still no idea where "summation" comes in - I'm glad you managed to follow the question, as it still seems bizarrely explained to me.

Comment: @JonSkeet It's 1 based because sql <3's its 1 [based](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) [indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx).

Comment: @JonSkeet I mean first elements' count of the arrays.

Comment: It still isn't clear why you'd use the word "summation" here - nothing is being summed.

Comment: Same values' counts summed into a cell in list.

Comment: @JonSkeet If I had to guess (and team16 please correct me if I am wrong) but English may not be is first language. To a [ESL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_as_a_second_or_foreign_language) person I can easily see how "count of each distinct number" becomes "summation"

Comment: Ok. You are right. My English is insufficient. However, the question's title is clear, isn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
anotherList = list.Select(a => a[0]) // project each array to its first item
                  .GroupBy(x => x)   // group first items by their value
                  .Select(g => g.Count())  // select count of same items
                  .ToList();
```

Output:

```
[ 3, 1, 1, 2 ]
```

NOTE: GroupBy internally uses Lookup which returns groups in same order as the are added, so it seems to be what you want.

UPDATE: Approach which does not depend on internal implementation of GroupBy

```
anotherList = list.Select((a,i) => new { Item = a[0], Index = i })
                  .GroupBy(x => x.Item)
                  .OrderBy(g => g.Min(x => x.Index))
                  .Select(g => g.Count())
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: lol, and this is why I like linq, [you took the words right out of my mouth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23809089/how-to-count-same-elements-in-different-arrays-in-c-sharp#comment36625227_23809089).

Comment: One note if the behavior of `Lookup`, the output order is not "well defined" so at any later time they could choose to change how ordering is handled.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yes, completely agree with you! But currently *test passes* and I believe its simplest solution. Anyway, added another, implementation independent solution:)

Comment: @team16sah I recommend [LINQ Fundamentals](http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/linq-fundamentals) course by pluralsight, and [Re-implementing LINQ](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/09/03/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-1-introduction.aspx) series

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: The order of `Enumerable.GroupBy` is well-defined.  From [the Enumerable.GroupBy documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501.aspx): "The IGrouping<TKey, TElement> objects are yielded in an order based on the order of the elements in source that produced the first key of each IGrouping<TKey, TElement>. Elements in a grouping are yielded in the order they appear in source."

Comment: @Quartermeister `Enumerable.GroupBy`, but IGrouping is not. If you are using `Queryable.GroupBy` it states [from the documenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534492(v=vs.100).aspx) "The query behavior that occurs as a result of executing an expression tree that represents calling [the function] ***depends on the implementation of the type of the source parameter***. The expected behavior is that it groups the elements of source by a key value that is obtained by invoking keySelector on each element." So it is up to the data provider to decide the ordering.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Very true!  The OP has a list of arrays, so in this case it's Linq-to-Objects and the order is well-defined, but that's definitely something to be careful about when using other query providers.